# How can I combine multiple scope models in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have

```
    $scope.formTitle = '';
    $scope.formDesc = '';
    $scope.fields = [];
```

but would like to combine these into one `$scope.theForm` so I can have one object that would be easily converted into JSON.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use a normal JS object like you would anywhere else. For completeness, this isn't JSON until it's JSON--until then, it's just an object.

Comment: Dude, @DaveNewton, this is specific to Angular and you removed that from the title. I also want the output to be in JSON, like I said. That's the entire reason I need them combined. You butchered my question.

Comment: Dude, you don't tag questions on SO in the title; this is in the FAQ. Your question has nothing to do with JSON, and everything to do with plain old JS objects. JSON conversion happens later. I butchered nothing. Note how absolutely nothing in any of the answers has anything to do with JSON: the question, and answer, are JS basics.

Comment: I need it formatted in a way it makes sense in JSON, that's the entire point of me needing them combined. Also, you removed the reference to Angular.

Comment: ... As I stated, questions are not tagged in their titles, but by using the tags. This is in the FAQ. "Making sense in JSON" is... superfluous, since serialized a plain JS object to JSON "just works". You can get as bent out of shape as you want if it makes you feel better, but tags don't belong in the title, and if you have a proper JS object, JSON just happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from hosting your properties in a **wrapping class**. It is actually a recommended approach to use for the properties that are similar in purpose (like form properties for example).

```
// create wrapping class
$scope.theForm = {};

// add properties to the class
$scope.theForm.formTitle = '';
$scope.theForm.formDesc = '';
$scope.theForm.fields = [];
```

or you can declare the *properties* in the same *statement*, like this

```
$scope.theForm = {
    title: '',
    desc: '',
    fields: []
}
```

In *HTML*, and everywhere else, you simply access these *properties* using the *wrapping class* name as prefix: `theForm.formTitle`, `ng-repeat="field in theForm.fields"`, etc.

Comment: How would the impact my `ng-repeat="field in fields"` and `ng-switch="field.type"`?

Comment: ng-repeat="field in theForm.fields"; same for all others.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the last thing causing issues when I do all of this.. What would I change `$scope.fields.push({type: type, label:'Added Form Title', desc:'Added Form Desc', req:true});` to? I've tried `$scope.theForm.fields.push({type: type, label:'Added Form Title', desc:'Added Form Desc', req:true});` but it adds `field:` outside of the `fields` array.

Comment: @Reuben What's `field`? It's not in anything you're pushing onto `fields`.

Comment: My `ng-repeat` has `field in theForm.fields` it worked before combining everything.

Comment: `type: type` -> what is the second type? Shouldn't it be `type: 'type'`?

Comment: Nope, it's a variable brought in through `var type = ui.draggable.attr("id");` which was also working before combining. It still does work after combining.

Comment: The code you have posted looks OK, your problem lies somewhere else I think. Maybe you should open another question and show all the related code.

Comment: Even though it was all working fine before combining the scopes?

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu, take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490391/field-not-repeating-properly-in-angular-after-combining-scopes

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.theForm = {
    title: '',
    desc: '',
    fields: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
$scope.theForm = {
    formTitle: '',
    formDesc: '',
    fields: []
}
```

Maybe instead of `theForm` you want to call it `data` or `model` or `dataModel`.

But **you don't need to concretely define this on your scope** if you are getting it from as a JSON object. In this example I won't use `$scope` either. I will use a resolve object to get the JSON object;

```
MyController.resolve = {
    'myDataObject': ['myService', function(myservice] {
         return myService.getMyDataObjectPromise();
     }]
}
MyController.$inject = ['myDataObject'];
function MyController(myJsonObject) {

   this.data = myJsonObject;

}
```

In your uiRouter or ngRouter you will point the `resolve` object for this controller as `MyController.resolve`. As well you will this example uses the `controllerAs` syntax. So with `controller: 'MyController as vs'` the view would access the data with `vm.data`.